# Should I use static work pool or dynamic work pool (of threads)?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm running a pthreads program that works very nicely, however I don't see the speedup I would expect.  I suspect that I spend to much time creating and destroying my threads.

I'm at no time running more threads than I have cpus.

Over a period of 20 minutes I'm creating a approximately 5000 threads.

My question is if it's worthwhile implementing a proper static work pool, such that I will only allocate a static number of workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should measure where your app is spending all of it's time.  That comes out to about 4 or 5 thread creations per second, which is a lot but probably not where you're spending all of your time.

That said, however, if you're always limiting yourself to N threads, where N is the number of CPUs, the you should probably just create N threads up front and schedule work to run on each thread using some algorithm that makes sense wrt the calculation you're doing.

Comment: Indeed thread creation is not the bottleneck. On a low-end system, thread creation takes around 30 microseconds. 150000 microseconds out of 20 minutes is nothing.

Comment: Definitely check what your threads are doing.   Your CPU might be able to handle multiple instructions at a time, but what about other pieces of hardware/software your code is talking to?   If, for example, they are writing to the HDD which is single-threaded then you will see no performance increase.

Comment: Yes, @SlappyTheFish makes a good point.  Since we know nothing about the problem space, it's hard to give advice.  But in general checking for resource contention in multithreaded programs is a good place to find bottlenecks.